# ROS Answers SE migration: Octave in ROS

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am in learning phase with the ROS, of of the languages that I want to use is Octave, but I can not add the libraries. How I can do this?.

Greetings, and sorry for my English, I speak not very well.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/9887/octave-in-ros/) by [mgc0003](https://answers.ros.org/users/495/mgc0003/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2011-05-03

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

There are no longer libraries for Octave support in ROS.  The 'rosoct' client library was last compatible with ROS C Turtle.  You can download it here:

https://code.ros.org/svn/ros/stacks/ros_experimental/branches/cturtle/rosoct/

---

Originally posted by [kwc](https://answers.ros.org/users/11/kwc/) with karma: 12244 on 2011-06-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0